# Как запустить функцию в потоке из другого потока Python?

Tags: python, threading

Допустим у меня есть код

```
import threading
from discord.ext import commands

def robot():
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

    def test():
        print("Эта функция в другом потоке")
        
    bot.run("token")

threads = []

for i in range(3):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=robot)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

как я могу выполнить в каждом потоке функцию test?